# Create table statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create the following table in MYSQL and is giving errors,

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUS_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
CUS_NAME VARCHAR,
CUS_DOB DATE,
CUS_ADDR VARCHAR,
CUS_EMAIL VARCHAR,
CUS_TEL VARCHAR,
CUS_PW VARCHAR,
CUS_JOINDATE DATETIME,
CUS_LASTACCESS DATE)

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' CUS_DOB DATE, CUS_ADDR VARCHAR, CUS_EMAIL VARCHAR, CUS_TEL VARCHAR, CUS_PW' at line 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify a length for your VARCHAR fields and also make your AUTO_INCREMENT field a the primary key.  I made up lengths here for you - you should consider the maximum length that you actually want for each field.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUS_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
CUS_NAME VARCHAR(30),
CUS_DOB DATE,
CUS_ADDR VARCHAR(50),
CUS_EMAIL VARCHAR(30),
CUS_TEL VARCHAR(20),
CUS_PW VARCHAR(30),
CUS_JOINDATE DATETIME,
CUS_LASTACCESS DATE)
```

A few other suggestions:

1. Specify the ENGINE (InnoDB or MyISAM)
2. Get rid of the CUS_ prefix to all the fields.  You know they are CUSTOMERS.  They are in the CUSTOMERS table
3. CUS_PW looks suspiciously like a password field.  Do not, under any cirucmstances, ever, in any environment, store customer passwords in plain text in the database.  Never, never.

Here is the MySQL Documentation for [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) and for the [data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/data-types.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i shall never ever ever ever store passwords in plain text :)

Answer (score 5):

There are two things wrong with it.

Firstly, you need to specify maximum data lengths for the `VARCHAR` columns.

Secondly, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column has to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.

The following DDL statement will work:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER ( 
  CUS_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  CUS_NAME VARCHAR(32), 
  CUS_DOB DATE, 
  CUS_ADDR VARCHAR(128), 
  CUS_EMAIL VARCHAR(64), 
  CUS_TEL VARCHAR(16), 
  CUS_PW VARCHAR(32), 
  CUS_JOINDATE DATETIME, 
  CUS_LASTACCESS DATE
);
```

Obviously you'll need to change the `VARCHAR` types to reflect the sizes needed for your data.

Comment: Can't i add the primary key constraint after the creation of all tables like `ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER ADD CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PK PRIMARY KEY (CUS_ID)`

Comment: Not if you include `AUTO_INCREMENT` in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: @Phil: To be precise, an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column does not need to be the Primary Key (or part of it). It just needs to be indexed, alhtough I can't imagine a use for that (and it's certainly not the case here).